# Change the order of fields in normal serializer response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using Django REST framework I want to change the serializer response fields order dynamically by a list of given field names.

Output from DRF is the following:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 25,
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Sam",
      "age": 20,
      "id": 8
    }
  ]
}
```

My filed order list is:

```
order_list = ['id', 'age', 'name']
```

What I want is:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "age": 25,
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "age": 20,
      "name": "Sam"
    }
  ]
}
```

Serializer code:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    age = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Please post the serializer.

Comment: @SachinKukreja I have updated with serializer, i want to do it with out touching the filed declaration in serializer

Answer (score 4):

To change the ordering, you will need to change the field definition in the serializer meta class.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    age = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta(object):
         fields = ( # this needs to be ordered properly
             'id',
             'age',
             'name',
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the serializer data and order the fields using [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).
The data in the serializer is already using `OrderedDict`, but we can use it to further order accordingly.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = serializer.data
ordered_data = []
for item in data:
     item_dict = OrderedDict()
     item_dict['id'] = item['id']
     item_dict['age'] = item['age']
     item_dict['name'] = item['name']
     ordered_data.append(item_dict)
```